# "in the non-rigorous way" vs. "in a non-rigorous way"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

I answered a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/420102/239593) just now, where I said

> Actually, you are calculating the false positive rate (FPR) instead of
>   the false positive, it seems that wiki example uses this term **in the non-rigorous way**.

I am concerned I misuse the expression, so, "in **the** non-rigorous way" or "in **a** non-rigorous way", which one is idiomatic?

If you have a more idiomatic and clear expression about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there were only two choices, one specific rigorous method and one specific *non*-rigorous method, then the definite article (*the*) makes sense.

However, since there are **many** ways to not be rigorous (e.g. sloppy measurements, using uncalibrated tools, failure to have a control, etc.), then the **indefinite** article (*a*) would apply.